# How to Cache Additional Items in a Workbox Plugin

Tags: service-worker, workbox, workbox-webpack-plugin

I'd like to write a Workbox plugin that intercepts a particular API call, does some logic (omitted from the code below) that determines other URL's that can be cached, then adds them to the runtime cache.

```js
export class PreCachePlugin implements WorkboxPlugin {
  fetchDidSucceed: WorkboxPlugin["fetchDidSucceed"] = async ({
    response,
  }) => {
    if (response.ok) {
      const clonedResponse = await response.clone();
      const json = await clonedResponse.json();
      const urls: string[] = getUrlsToCache(json); // Omitting this logic.
      await Promise.all(urls.map(url => {
        const response = await fetch(url);
        // TODO: How do I fetch these URL's and put them in the cache configured
        // below while still respecting the expiration.maxEntries setting below?
      }));
    }
  }
}
```

I am using `GenerateSW` with `workbox-webpack-plugin` and adding my plugin:

```js
new GenerateSW({
  include: [/\.js$/, /\.json$/, /\.html$/],
  runtimeCaching: [
    {
      urlPattern: ({ url }) => url.toString().endsWith("/foo"),
      handler: "StaleWhileRevalidate",
      options: {
        cacheName: "Foo",
        expiration: { maxEntries: 100 },
        plugins: [
          new PreCachePlugin(),
        ],
      },
    },
  ],
  swDest: "./sw.js",
}
```

How do I fetch the above new URL's and put them in the configured runtime cache while still respecting the `expiration.maxEntries` settings?